# Is is true? A semi-Eulerian graph cannot exist if we can find a complete graph with the same number of edges

Tags: graph-theory

I was trying out some Graphs and wondered if what I found was true. I am reasonably confident up to where I placed the asterix.

Take a semi-Eulerian graph $G$ with $m$ edges. A complete graph with $n$ vertices has $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ edges.

For a complete graph, all the vertices have the same degrees and hence there can never be a complete semi-Eulerian graph. Hence a complete graph satisfying $\frac{1}{2}n(n – 1) = m$ cannot have integer values of $n$, or this complete semi-Eulerian graph would actually exist. Using the quadratic formula gives $\frac{1}{2}((1 + 8m)^{1/2} + 1)$ as the values of $n$ (discarding the negative sign as $n > 0$), which are not integers.

*However, this **is** an integer for certain $m$ – if this is true, then it means that, as all $K_n$ exist, then a semi-Eulerian graph cannot exist if we can find a complete graph with the same number of edges. So $m$ cannot equal $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$, where $n$ is an integer. One example using this is $m = 3$ and I can't seem to draw it.

Comment: According to [some writers](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Semi-Eulerian_Graph) "A graph is called semi-Eulerian if it contains an Eulerian trail" and ". . . an Eulerian graph is also semi-Eulerian . . ." According to [other writers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) "A graph that has an Eulerian trail but not an Eulerian circuit is called semi-Eulerian." If you have to use this silly "semi-Eulerian" instead of the standard term "traversable", it might be a good idea to tell us which definition of "semi-Eulerian" you're using.

Comment: "there can never be a complete semi-Eulerian graph." What is $K_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By way of counter-example - if I understood your assertion correctly -  here is a semi-eulerian graph with $21$ edges:

[image]

Maybe that was unnecessarily flashy... here's one with only $6$ edges:

[image]

Effectively by adding extra degree-$2$ nodes into the bottom loop (square) of the 6-edge graph, you can make a semi-eulerian graph with any number of edges you want.

Comment: I'm probably wrong but aren't there 3 odd vertices here?

Comment: I think I've actually found 4 odd vertices: the top left, top right, bottom right vertices of the large square, and the bottom left of the triangle

Comment: All the vertices on the square ( and the centre too) are degree-4

Comment: Sorry I can't count!

Comment: I realised my error. When saying a semi-Eulerian complete graph, then this graph must have $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, ans we require the semi-eulerian graph itself too to have $n$ vertices, from which the proof breaks down

Comment: Isn't $P_{m+1}$ a semi-Eulerian graph with $m$ edges? What am I missing?

Comment: @bof you're not missing anything - there are plenty of counterexamples.